# Div's keep moving position?

Tags: html, css, position

My header should look like this.

[image]

but every hour or so it reverts to this.

[image]

I have it set up so that there are two divs behind the main image so that they can be repeated no matter how wide the user's browser is.

the problem is that the images change position (they move up or down) whether I'm working on the layout or not. I don't know what is causing it to change every so often, but it's driving me nuts!!

The website is **www.rheanna.net** (sorry i can't post more than 2 links right now) in case you need to check out anything that I forgot to provide here.

The applicable header HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="top1"></div><div id="top2"></div>
<div class="container">
<div id="logo-area">
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
#top1 {
    width:49%;
    position:absolute;
    top:91px;
    left:0;
    height:127px;
    background:url("http://rheanna.net/images/topLeft_bg.gif") repeat-x;
    z-index:-10;
    }
#top2 {
    width: 49%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 91px;
    right: 0;
    height: 141px;
    background: url("http://rheanna.net/images/topRight_bg.gif") repeat-x;
    z-index: -10;
}
.container { text-align: left; margin: 0 auto; width: 960px; position: relative; }
.container #logo-area { text-align: center; margin-bottom: 57px; }
```

If anybody has any ideas of why it would be changing position on me, I would greatly appreciate your input!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you are setting elements have the position property of absolute and you try to align the with other elements you should wrap them in another element such as a div or section tag and give it the position over relative.

Your current code seems a little messy therefore I've recoded your desired design element. Your Logo area will need to be moved outside of it's current container and left sitting on it's own after your header.

**CSS**

```
.LogoArea {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 960px;
    margin-top: -60px;
    /* margin-bottom: 60px; */
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}
.LogoArea>.LeftStripe,
.LogoArea>.RightStripe {
    width: 49%!important;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -10;
}
.LogoArea>.LeftStripe {
    background: url("/images/topLeft_bg.gif") repeat-x;
    background-position: 0 -72px;
    height: 35px!important;
    top: 72px;
}
.LogoArea>.RightStripe {
    background: url("/images/topRight_bg.gif") repeat-x;
    right: 0;
    height: 21px;
    background-position: 0 -120px;
    top: 120px;
}
.LogoArea>.Logo {
    background: url("/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/logo.jpg");
    width: 781px;
    height: 245px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.LogoArea>.DonateLink {
    width: 21px;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: calc(-364px/2);
    position: absolute;
    top: 74px;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 27px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="LogoArea">
    <div class="LeftStripe"></div>
    <div class="RightStripe"></div>
    <div class="Logo"></div>
    <a href="YOUR DONATION LINK HERE" title="Donate using PayPal" class="DonateLink">Donate</a>
</div>
```

The HTML part should be placed in your header file at the bottom. Before `<!-- end #main-header -->` as your logo makes up part of your header.

I hope this improved answer makes more sense and overall works better.

> I have also provided additional mobile support

**MOBILE CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 960px) {
    .LogoArea {min-width:initial;}
    .LogoArea>.RightStripe,
    .LogoArea>.LeftStripe {display:none;}
    .LogoArea>.Logo {width: 100%;background-size:cover;height: 215px;}
    .container, .page #left-area, .single-post #left-area {width:100%;margin:0;}
    .LogoArea>.DonateLink {display: none;}
}
@media (max-width: 701px) {
    .LogoArea>.Logo {height: 190px}
}
@media (max-width: 625px) {
    .LogoArea>.Logo {height: 170px}
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {
    .LogoArea>.Logo {height: 145px}
}

@media (max-width: 459px) {
    .LogoArea>.Logo {height: 120px}
}

@media (max-width: 439px) {
    .LogoArea>.Logo {BACKGROUND-IMAGE: NONE;height: auto;}
    .LogoArea>.Logo:before {
   CONTENT:"RHEANNA DOT NET";
   font-size: 14px;
   DISPLAY:BLOCK;
   text-align:center;
   padding: 1em;
   font-family: cursive, sans-serif;
   color: #8BC34A;
   }.LogoArea>.Logo:after {
   CONTENT:"A collection of life, love and memories.";
   font-size: .35em;
   DISPLAY:BLOCK;
   text-align:center;
   padding: 1em;
   padding-top:0;
   color: #607D8B;
   margin-top: -10px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   padding-bottom: 2em;
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. So far it looks good. I will report back later if I find it moves again. Thank you.

Comment: @PHPN00b Please update with new example it has improved formatting and it more efficient.

Comment: @PHPN00b in you wordpress sites header file locate your stylesheet and next to the extension the part that says `<link rel="stylesheet" href="domain.com/wp-content/blah/css/**style.css**" /> add `<?php echo "?v=".rand(); ?>` whilst developing your site and once your done developing your site simply remove it or comment it out. This will stop your stylesheet from caching and allow updates to be visible right away.

Comment: thank you. I've accepted your answer. ;) I don't see how it changes much of what I was already doing though (other than the 59px), but hopefully it refrains from moving up or down anymore! Thanks again :D - ETA: OH! Thanks for the tip, I've never seen that before.

Comment: If it was my own site I would actually redo that aspect of the site the coding for it is horrendous, I'll create a better solution for you a update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Here is what it looks like: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri()."?v=".rand();?>" type="text/css" />`  I assume that is what you meant for me to do. Also, yeah, I'm trying to work with a pre-made wordpress theme, so it is a bit messy when trying to move things around myself (I'm not the world's best coder - but maybe someday ;) )

Comment: @PHPN00b yeah that's what i mean when your finished developing remove the `."?v=".rand();` part also I'm going to update my answer with a much better way of achieving your logo effect?

Comment: Awesome. Keep in mind that I have a image map on my logo - so there is a link ONLY on the "D" in "dot" if it has a negative z-index, that link is unclickable. Thank you for you help!!!

Comment: @PHPN00b is this a good practice as a user wouldn't even know that you can donate. I've created a better solution that covers the problem with your flower being slightly chopped at the bottom. UPDATED ANSWER.

Comment: Your code resulted in this: [link](http://rheanna.net/wp-content/themes/lucid-child/images/test.png) - and I don't really want people to know you can donate necessarily. I actually wanted it to be more of a "secret" link. More for my personal use rather than general public use. I'm not looking for money.

Comment: @PHPN00b Move the block of code just after `</header>` and for the link add `visibility:hidden` and add `tab-index="-1"` to the link element UPDATING ANSWER

Comment: @PHPN00b You should also update the CSS code with the one provided so that it targets those elements directly.

Comment: I've updated the code - the donate link will have to be moved around because I want it over the "D" in "dot" - and the way you have it set up it's unclickable. However, I really do appreciate all your help!!

Comment: @PHPN00b fixed the hidden donation link [UPDATING CODE]

Comment: @PHPN00b The code has been updated now you can have the hidden link over the "D" character

Comment: @PHPN00b I've added additional CSS for mobile support

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the top values? 59px works for both `top1` and `top2`?

Alternatively, you could just make the whole header one image instead of having 3 separate ones.

Edit: Sorry, I didn't notice the repeat-x.

Comment: Yes, I could change it to be 59px, but that doesn't fix the fact that it moves again. The whole problem is that it moves no matter how far from the top I put it. And having a single image would not allow me to repeat just the sides...

Comment: I think this makes sense. `top:59px;` is what it should be because the `<header>` height is exactly 59px and the 2 background top divs need to render right after the `<header>`. I would set your `#main-header` with a `height: 59px;` to ensure it doesn't get bigger on smaller screens when words wrap